# Which property is used to change the font of an element?

Tags: css, fonts, font-family

I took [a CSS quiz](http://www.w3schools.com/quiztest/quiztest.asp?qtest=CSS) at w3schools.com, and I got all of the answers correct except the one below. I tried to search on the subject, but as far as I can see the answer should be correct. Where am I wrong? Really confused with this.

> **15. Which property is used to change the font of an element?**
>
> **You answered:**
>
> font-family
>
> Wrong Answer!

Comment: What's wrong with this question?

Comment: The question expresses a legitimate concern and shows the will to learn, shouldn't we be encouraging such behaviour?

Comment: This is a "do my homework" question at best that can be answered by simply looking at the two possible answers. "Font" or "font-family" are the only choices.

Comment: On a side-note w3schools isn't a reliable source to learn from, check out [css tricks](http://css-tricks.com) and [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) when in doubt/learning things.

Comment: @TylerH Asking a specific question about why his answer is wrong on a code quiz is not a "do my homework" question IMO. He's just wanting to learn which is the entire purpose of SO

Comment: It would be nice if the quiz itself would provide the explanation, but that aside, I agree with Zach here. Nobody asked to 'do' anything, Attila is just asking for information/explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `font` property is the one that changes all aspects of a font, including family, style and weight. The `font-family` property only changes the font-family. The family is a group of related fonts (or [typefaces](http://www.fastcodesign.com/3028971/whats-the-difference-between-a-font-and-a-typeface)).

So 'Comic Sans MS' is a font family, while 'Comic Sans MS Bold 10pt' is a font. In speech, people tend to mix up those terms.

Comment: aaaa... got it now, so the font will set all the font properties in one declaration. thanks. all clear. never used that property like that.

Comment: 15. Which property is used to change the font of an element?

You answered:

font
 Wrong Answer!    - So basically the correct answer is both (font and font-family)

Comment: Good to know. I haven't done the quiz, so I didn't know the available options. But yes, if you look at it that way, then `font-family` also changes the overal appearance of a font. -edit- Done it. 100% Woohoo! :D

Comment: Yes, sorry I did not mention first all the 3 possible answers, but after I did the quiz it did not show them. So I did it 3 times and finally the 3rd answer was correct. But anyway this is something I will never forget :) Tricky question, this is why I love tests, always learn something from them :D But your answer clarified me the whole thing!

Answer (score 5):

[`font` and `font-family` do different things](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101019145250AA05D2L):

> Best illustrated with an example. Arial is a font family. Arial Bold 14 point is a type font. Helvetica is a font family. Helvetica Ultra Compressed 26 point is a type font.

Comment: You should link to the Yahoo Answer you quoted

Comment: As you can tell by the quotes that were in there originally, I didn't intend for it to be a plagiarism, just didn't deem it as being link-worthy. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

The quiz says that the correct answer is that both `font-family` and `font` can be used to set the font. This can be characterized as correct, when the other options are `font-family` alone and `font` alone. This question, and the quiz in its entirety, is not as seriously wrong as much of w3schools content (see http://w3fools.com), just largely pointless and inaccurate.

The `font-family` property sets, as the name suggests, the font family alone. The `font` shorthand sets all normally settable font properties and also line height. The interpretation of the question revolves around the question “what is a font?” If you mean font family, then `font-family` sets that only, whereas `font` also sets font size, font weight, etc. If you mean a specific typeface in a specific size, specific weight etc., then only `font` does that.

Answer (score 0):

```
15. Which property is used to change the font of an element?

You answered:

font
 Wrong Answer!
```

Basically the correct answer is both of them (font anf font-family)