# Can I select all divs inside another div?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if there was any way to reference all divs inside of a specific div using CSS (e.g. Using only one CSS rule, can I make everything inside a `<div>` element--where that div element is inside another `<div>` element--have red text.)

That might sound a little complicated, so let me give you the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<title>Chic Cyles</title>

</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<h1>Chic Cycling</h1>
<div id="left">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam varius tincidunt nisl, nec laoreet risus lobortis eget. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam mi velit, imperdiet eu odio quis, lobortis eleifend mi. Cras neque neque, accumsan et urna et, bibendum fringilla nisl. Sed pretium congue magna. Phasellus id rutrum ipsum. Vestibulum id nulla eleifend ligula sollicitudin volutpat. Vivamus eu dolor luctus, sodales neque vitae, adipiscing erat. Duis adipiscing felis sed elit suscipit, nec egestas turpis ullamcorper. In auctor, lacus eget malesuada tristique, felis ipsum ultrices felis, sed mattis elit sapien quis ipsum. Nunc gravida nulla velit, non semper eros ullamcorper non. Vestibulum viverra orci vitae pharetra pulvinar. Sed vulputate sodales orci, nec gravida odio. Vivamus lobortis nec nisl ut lobortis.

Suspendisse at justo felis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam varius tincidunt nisl, nec laoreet risus lobortis eget. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam mi velit, imperdiet eu odio quis, lobortis eleifend mi. Cras neque neque, accumsan et urna et, bibendum fringilla nisl. Sed pretium congue magna. Phasellus id rutrum ipsum. Vestibulum id nulla eleifend ligula sollicitudin volutpat. Vivamus eu dolor luctus, sodales neque vitae, adipiscing erat. Duis adipiscing felis sed elit suscipit, nec egestas turpis ullamcorper. In auctor, lacus eget malesuada tristique, felis ipsum ultrices felis, sed mattis elit sapien quis ipsum. Nunc gravida nulla velit, non semper eros ullamcorper non. Vestibulum viverra orci vitae pharetra pulvinar. Sed vulputate sodales orci, nec gravida odio. Vivamus lobortis nec nisl ut lobortis.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam varius tincidunt nisl, nec laoreet risus lobortis eget. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam mi velit, imperdiet eu odio quis, lobortis eleifend mi. Cras neque neque, accumsan et urna et, bibendum fringill.</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In my stylesheet, could there be a way to make all text inside the div(s) that are inside the "wrapper" div red?

Comment: `#wrapper div {color: red;}`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the most fundamental basic CSS selectors.

Comment: @Harry Unnecessarily specific; don't need the first "div"

Comment: @TylerH: Absolutely agreed mate. Initially I wanted to post `div.wrapper` and only then realized it was `id` and then forgot to edit :D

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I would have agreed, but the community (at least somewhat) spoke on a similar matter here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25162273/which-property-is-used-to-change-the-font-of-an-element

Comment: Please try to complete a most basic tutorial about CSS selectors before asking questions here on SO. It will benefit you much more.

Comment: @TylerH What makes that question similar in your mind? I have no idea how is that a similar matter.

Comment: @kapa Incredibly basic premise of CSS.

Comment: @TylerH I think the OP there simply did not understand the difference between the terms "font" and "font family", it is not really a CSS issue.

Comment: @NicoA if any of the answers helped you/answered your question, please consider clicking the "accept as an answer" checkmark next to that answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using only CSS:

```
#wrapper div {
    color: red;
}
```

This is a basic method for selecting elements based on their ancestors, commonly called a **descendant selector**. With this code, it's looking for a div that has an ancestor with the ID of `wrapper`. Note that the `wrapper` div doesn't have to be a direct parent anywhere, just a **direct ancestor** (that is, it can't be an "uncle".

Comment: This will not work while have some TAGs inside #wrapper > DIV.

Comment: @KushalJayswal The selector in your comment is not the same as the selector in my answer.

Comment: I trying to show different ways of doing it.

Comment: Why was this downvoted today? @KushalJayswal did you downvote it?

Comment: Nope. I just added comment.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for related question before posting yours because questions seems fundamental one.

You can add this CSS into your style-sheet:

```
#wrapper div,
#wrapper div span,
#wrapper div em,
#wrapper div p{
    color: #f00;
}
```

OR you can simply write...

```
#wrapper div, 
#wrapper div *{
    color: #f00;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

CSS:

```
#wrapper div{
    color: "red"
}
```

With jQuery if you want to dynamically change the color after the page loads:

```
$("#wrapper div").css({
    color: "red";
});
```

JavaScript if you to dynamically change the color, but don't want to load jQuery:

```
var myThing = document.querySelectorAll("#wrapper div");
for(var i = 0; i < myThing.length; i++){
    myThing[i].style.color = "red";
}
```

Comment: Please add reason while marking negative.

Comment: @AmitKansal: I didn't downvote so can't revoke but the reason I think was because the initial answer was using jQuery when it was not necessary/tagged.

Comment: I'm not revoking my DV because you're still suggesting jQuery. jQuery should NOT be used for such trivial tasks! It's like getting an industrial sledgehammer to hang a picture on a wall!

Comment: Did not up-vote because you are pushing jQuery; if it was real JavaScript I would have.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I cleared up the answer as to when you should use JS for this

Comment: @LloydBanks While that is good and all the problem is when I search on Google about 90% of the time I **explicitly** use -jquery. jQuery is so prolific it's practically a plague. Beware of adding unnecessary dependencies.

Comment: @Harry ok but when I saw the answer it was with both approaches CSS and JQuery. That's why I got confused why somebody put it down-vote.

Comment: Niet is right: this does not require JavaScript of any kind to achieve, and introducing it for this task is way too much overhead for a simple color change. Your CSS is also incorrect; it won't work with quotation marks. So for those things, DV.